# How to write a condition for a table in an outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to display all sessions with the date, which is taken from the `schedule_session` table by joining it, and filtering by `class_id.`

```
select * from sessions s 
left join schedule_session ss on ss.session_id = s.id 
where ss.class_id = 5
```

This query does not return all sessions because I am saying where `class_id = 5` so it returns only specific class sessions. Is there any method that I can first get all sessions and show in the `date` property, and the date from the `schedule_session` if it exists for that particular session. So in the end I have all sessions but haven't assigned any `date` for it.

So I want all sessions and show the value of `date` if it exists for that class, if not show date as `null` or `blank`.

Thanks

Comment: Change WHERE to AND - and surely you can manage to come up with a better title.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear description but i think below is your solution.

```
select * from sessions s 
left join schedule_session ss on ss.session_id = s.id and ss.class_id = 5
```